# Customise Visual Studio 2017 toolbar - open a specific file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Short of writing a VS add-in, is there a way to add a button to a VS toolbar which opens a specific xml file from a fixed location in a new editor window?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Favorite Documents](https://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension to add a link to a file and then open it from the Favorites menu.